# The output dimension of dense layer in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am writing a Alexnet of Cifar10 Implementation on tensorflow. The following is the code for the last few layers

```
   ## pool5
    pool5 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv5,
                         ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                         strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                         padding="SAME",
                         name='pool5')
    print_activations(pool5)

    # ## Flatten
    # pool5=tf.contrib.layers.flatten(pool5, outputs_collections=None, scope=None)

    ## FC1
    fc1=tf.layers.dense(pool5, 4096, activation=tf.nn.relu,  trainable=True)
    print_activations(fc1)

    ## FC2
    fc2=tf.layers.dense(fc1, 4096, activation=tf.nn.relu,  trainable=True)
    print_activations(fc2)

    ## Ouput
    out1=tf.layers.dense(fc2, 10, activation=None,  trainable=True)
```

TO my understanding, the output of the last layer should be tensor with length 10. Considering batch size, it should be [None, 10]. However, when I return 'out1.shape.dims', I got [None, None, None, 10]. Anyone knows what I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Tensorflow is weird like that, out1 is a layer and you can't treat it as a function with specified output. I believe the correct way to get the output is calling `tf.function([ first_layer], [last_layer])(data)` ?

Comment: Why did you disable tf.contrib.layers.flatten ? it was needed  before full connected layers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just checked the document. The tf.layers.dense will return a tensor with same dimension of its input. The output from the previous conv2d is 4-D thats why here I got 4-D output from dense layers. I probably should add a flatten layer